how to get google Doc file content in react
I want to get google docs file content and render its content in react component. i have client id and secret key. And alo ihave done auth0 setup as which give me user details.
seEffect(() => {
    const fetchDoc = async () => {
      try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
          audience: "https://www.googleapis.com/",
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly",
        });

        const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2({
          clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
          clientSecret: "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
        });

        auth.setCredentials({
          access_token: accessToken,
        });

        const docs = google.docs({ version: "v1", auth });
        const response = await docs.documents.get({
          documentId: "1YUUy66Z6UUfqP-fBY52X0WHlChQIWARmzAGHktB2k08",
        });
        const content = response.data.body.content;
        let textContent = "";
        if (content) {
          content.forEach((element: any) => {
            if (element.paragraph) {
              element.paragraph.elements.forEach((e: any) => {
                if (e.textRun) {
                  textContent += e.textRun.content + "\n";
                }
              });
            }
          }); }

        setDocContent(textContent);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching Google Docs file:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchDoc();
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

